# Some monad wrapping/unwrapping/binding mess involving a container containing a Maybe

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Here's a bit of sample code

```
foo :: a -> Identity (Maybe a)
foo a = do
  maybeStuff <- getStuffSometimes a
  return $ case maybeStuff of                  -- this "case" stuff is the kind
    Just stuff -> Just $ getStuffAlways stuff  -- of code I'd expect the Maybe
    Nothing -> Nothing                         -- monad to help with

getStuffSometimes :: a -> Identity (Maybe a)
getStuffSometimes a = return $ Just a

getStuffAlways :: a -> Identity a
getStuffAlways = return

-- ERROR (on the return statement of the do block)
-- Expected type: Identity (Maybe a)
--   Actual type: Identity (Maybe (Identity a))
```

It might be a little unclear what I'm trying to do, so here's a more detailed description:

- All of the interesting things are wrapped in a computational context/container -- in this case, `Identity`, for the sake of demonstration.  In my actual code I have another monad of course.
- `foo` and `getStuffSometimes` are supposed to take in something of type `a` and return a `Maybe a` wrapped in the context -- that is, they either return `Identity (Just a)` (the computation successful, or `Identity Nothing` (the computation failed).
- `getStuffAlways` is a computation that never fails -- it always returns `Identity a`.
- I want `foo` to:

  1. Run a failable computation
  2. If the failable computation fails, fail (with Nothing)
  3. If the failable computation suceeds, bind it with getStuffAlways, and return 
     `Just (result of getStuffAlways to the result of #1)`

Is this a use case situation for Monad Transformers?  In my case my actual monad is a bit complicated and is a stack of multiple transformers given by my library on top of IO and i'm not totally sure how to make it work for this situation (I'd ask it in another question of it ends up being that I have to use transformers)

---

### Follow up:

In real life I have something more like:

```
foo :: a -> Identity (a, Maybe a)
foo a = do
  firstPart <- getStuffAlways a

  maybeStuff <- getStuffSometimes a
  secondPart <- case maybeStuff of
    Just stuff -> Just $ getStuffAlways stuff
    Nothing -> Nothing

  return (firstPart, secondPart)
```

What would be the best way to construct the stack in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a use case for monad transformers.  Given a computation of type:

```
computation :: (Monad m) => m (Maybe a)
```

... you can wrap it in `MaybeT` using the `MaybeT` constructor of the same name:

```
MaybeT :: (Monad m) => m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a

MaybeT computation :: (Monad m) => MaybeT m a
```

Then you can just write:

```
foo :: MaybeT Identity a
foo = do
   stuff <- MaybeT getStuffSometimes
   lift $ getStuffAlways stuff
```

... and `MaybeT` will take care of all the `Nothing` checks for you, making sure to thread them through your other monad.

When your done, just use `runMaybeT` to unwrap the result, giving back an action in the base monad that returns a `Maybe`:

```
runMaybeT :: (Monad m) => MaybeT m a -> m (Maybe a)
```

For example:

```
runMaybeT foo :: Identity (Maybe a)
```

Edit: To answer your follow up question, you would just do:

```
foo a = do
    firstPart <- getStuffAlways
    secondPart <- runMaybeT $ do
        stuff <- MaybeT getStuffSometimes a
        lift $ getStuffAlways stuff
    return (firstPart, secondPart)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be good :)  I have a follow-up question.  What if `foo :: a -> Identity (a,Maybe a)` ?  That is, the fst of the tuple is a computation that can't fail, and a `snd` of it is.  How would I structure that?  Do I wrap the entire `foo` in a MaybeT?  Or have only `getStuffSometimes` be a MaybeT, and have `foo` call `runMaybeT`?

Comment: Actually I ran into some errors trying to implement this with concrete types (ie `String` instead of `a`): I get the error `Coudn't match expected type Maybe a0 with actual type String`; expected `Identity (Maybe a0)`, actual `Identity String`, in the return type of `getStuffAlways` in the second line of foo.

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out that the second `MaybeT` should be `lift`, and now everything works :)  I figured out my follow-up too.
Actually didn't noticed that you answered it, but thank you so much!